# SQL DB2 Conditional Select

Tags: sql, db2

I'm working on a DB2 stored procedure and am having a little trouble getting the results I want. The problem with the following query is that it does not return rows from table A that don't pass the final where clause. I would like to receive all rows from table A that meet the first WHERE clause (WHERE A.GENRC_CD_TYPE = 'MDAA'). Then, add an email column from table B for each of those rows(WHERE (A.DESC) = B.MATL_PLNR_ID).

```
    SELECT  A.GENRC_CD,
            A.DESC_30,
            A.DOL,
            A.DLU,
            A.LU_LID,
            B.EMAIL_ID_50
    FROM    GENRCCD A,
            MPPLNR B
    WHERE A.GENRC_CD_TYPE = 'MDAA'
    AND (A.DESC_30) = B.MATL_PLNR_ID;
```

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Then what you need is a LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT  A.GENRC_CD,
        A.DESC_30,
        A.DOL,
        A.DLU,
        A.LU_LID,
        B.EMAIL_ID_50
FROM    GENRCCD A LEFT JOIN
        MPPLNR B on A.DESC_30=B.MATL_PLNR_ID
WHERE A.GENRC_CD_TYPE = 'MDAA'
```